# I tried looping on HTML elements through JS. There seems to be an error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a slider (input tag) that receives an input as the user slides it. The value gets recorded and out of 100 rectangles already created 'value' of the 100 get colored. If I take the slier to 76, 76 rectangles should be shaded and all others should be white.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const carsContainer = document.querySelector('.cars-container');
const cars = carsContainer.querySelectorAll('.car');

slider.addEventListener('input', function () {
  const sliderValue = slider.value;
  console.log(sliderValue);

  for (let i = 0; i < sliderValue; i++) {
    cars[i].style.backgroundcolor = 'yellow';
  }
});
```

```css
.slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.cars-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.car {
  --size: 6.2rem;
  width: var(--size);
  height: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="5" class="slider" />
</div>

<div class="cars-container">
  <!-- 01 -->
  <div class="car"></div>
  .
  .
  .

  <!-- 100 -->
  <div class="car"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you running into problems. You say `there seems to be an error`, but don't say what's indicating that.

Comment: The code shown produces errors because the loop is trying to modify more than 2 `.car` elements when only 2 exist.  Is that the error you're referring to?

Comment: Do `console.log(cars.length)` to see if you have as many car elements as you think you do

Comment: @David I think the `...<!-- 100 -->` in the HTML snippet is supposed to indicate that the real code has 100 of them.

Comment: code should work as long as there are as many divs as your input max value suggest and you change your code to `cars[i].style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS solution which doesn't require re-toggling inline `background-color`:

(Note that [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) is [not very well supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has) yet)

```js
slider.addEventListener('input', function () {
  // Remove current .max
  document.querySelector('.max')?.classList.remove('max');
  // Add .max to the chosen .car
  cars[slider.value - 1].classList.add('max');
});
```

```css
.car:has(~ .max), .max {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Or */

.car {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.max ~ .div {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Try it:

```js
const carsContainer = document.querySelector('.cars-container');

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const car = document.createElement('div');
  car.classList.add('car');
  car.textContent = i + 1;
  carsContainer.appendChild(car);
}

const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const cars = carsContainer.querySelectorAll('.car');

slider.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.querySelector('.max')?.classList.remove('max');
  cars[slider.value - 1].classList.add('max');
});

slider.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

```css
.slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.cars-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1r);
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.car {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.max ~ .car {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="5" class="slider" />
</div>

<div class="cars-container"></div>
```

Comment: No need for the `has` here, you could set the default color to `yellow` and then `.max ~ .car { bg-color: #ccc }` https://jsfiddle.net/nsrm5ogt/

Answer (score 0):

When you lower the slider, you need to change all the rest of the rectangles back to white, otherwise they'll keep their yellow color from before.

```
slider.addEventListener('input', function () {
  const sliderValue = slider.value;
  console.log(sliderValue);

  for (let i = 0; i < sliderValue; i++) {
    cars[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
  for (let i = sliderValue; i < 100; i++) {
    cars[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
});
```

You also have a typo in `backgroundColor`; case is significant.